# "invalid signature" errors installing Arch linux on VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, system-installation, virtual-machine

I was trying to install Arch Linux, and everything was working so far. I downloaded the iso, created the profile on Virtualbox and booted the iso, successfully connected to the internet, updated the system clock, created the partitions, formatted them, and mounted them, but when I try to install the packages with the command

```
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel linux linux-firmware
```

it returns a bunch of errors:

[image: error: signature from "" is invalid File ... is corrupted Do you want to delete it]

I tried a lot of things, clearing the mirror list and pasting new links, downloading reflector, and synchronizing the hardware time again. I also have restarted like 5 times, but nothing seems to work.

I am still a noob so it is likely that it is a simple fix, but I've been trying for like days now, and I can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to report that updating VirtualBox to version `6.1.16` have solved the issue. Installation using `pacstrap` works as expected. Tested with `archlinux-2020.10.01-x86_64.iso`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your iso is a little old.  (It's arch, so yesterday's iso could be too old).  You can either get a new image from archlinux or try to update the pacman keyring.

If your boot media is writable, you can update the pacman keyring by updating the `archlinux-keyring` package with:

```
sudo pacman -Syy archlinux-keyring
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
```

---

If I couldn't get a newer ISO, and don't have writable boot-media, I'd probably try installing the base system, hoping that the base packages are available from the boot media without connecting to Arch's servers.  I haven't tested it, but this would be my plan:

```
pacstrap /mnt base
chroot /mnt
pacman -Syyu
pacman -S base-devel linux firmware-linux
```

---

The signatures on the server are newer than the signatures in your image.  Since your image is not configured to trust the signatures on the server, `pacman` refuses to continue with installation.  The `archlinux-keyring` package contains those signatures and is signed with a signature which doesn't really change.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work. The iso file that I downloaded is from today. I updated the keyrings and it said they were the same, and I tried installing again with both just the base and base,linux, and linuxfirmware, and I get the same result as the one in the image. If this might help, I copied this file for backup purposes earlier today incase anything went wrong so I wouldnt have to redownload it. Could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not very helpful but I am facing the same issue. Tried the `archlinux-2020.08.01-x86_64.iso` on Virtual Box and VMware Player with same result. However, when I put the iso on a USB and install on an actual computer it works fine.
For me it looks like virtualization issue but perhaps someone with more experience can explain exactly why. On the newest `VirtualBox-6.1.12-139181-Win.exe` I was also unable to run / install `manjaro-gnome-20.0.3-200606-linux56.iso` which is based on ArchLinux, however, other distros work normally (`ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso` / `kali-linux-2020.2-live-amd64.iso`)
Because Arch / Manjaro is on rolling release I think it might be compatibility issue with kernel as both of these use the newest one. Ubuntu / Kali use older one.

Comment: yeah i have the exact same iso, i was trying to do more research and found this forum: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255808 , as Scimmia says, apparently this is a known issue with VirtualBox 6.1, windows 10, and arch linux

Answer (score 0):

If you have an antivirus software installed then this can happen(probably not all antivirus software will cause this but some can). It happened with me when I was using Bitdefender antivirus; installed it on actual machine and it worked just fine. Otherwise you can follow @Stewart's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using VirtualBox on Windows 10. I had the exact same issue when attempting to install Arch Linux and it turned out that Windows was messing with VirtualBox's virtualization. Here is the reddit post that helped me fix the problem: [Arch Install: pacstrap fails due to corrupted package (PGP signature)](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/fk30ht/arch_install_pacstrap_fails_due_to_corrupted/).

[One of the comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/fk30ht/arch_install_pacstrap_fails_due_to_corrupted/fs0q0d4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) provided a link to [a VirtualBox thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339), which contained some helpful information and the solution to my problem.

My issue was that I had some [Windows features](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7247-turn-windows-features-off-windows-10-a.html#option1) enabled that *implicitly* enabled Hyper-V, which was messing with VirtualBox's virtualization. As a result, I had to ensure all the following features were disabled:

> - Application Guard
> - Credential Guard (see [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/downloa ... x?id=53337](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337))
> - Device Guard (see [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/downloa ... x?id=53337](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337))
> - * Guard
> - Containers
> - Hyper-V
> - Virtual Machine Platform
> - Windows Hypervisor Platform
> - Windows Sandbox
> - Windows Server Containers
> - Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) (WSL1 does not enable Hyper-V)

After ensuring all of the features on my computer that were listed above were disabled, `pacstrap` executed perfectly and I managed to complete the installation of Arch Linux without any more issues.